# Using IAsyncEnumerable in Content Result model class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

We have asp.net core 6 get rest apis where we are returning the list wrap with content result class. I know we can stream data in asp.net core web apis with IAsyncEnuerable but I wanted to know how we can do that with the following class returned.

```
     public class ContentResultList<T>
     {
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<T> Data { get; set; }

        public int TotalPages { get; set; } = 0;
        public int CurrrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
        public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
        public int TotalNumberOfRecords { get; set; } = 0;
        public int RecordsTotal { get; set; }
        public int RecordsFiltered { get; set; }
        public T Result { get; set; }
    }
```

Here you see that we have List Data but here I want to have IAsyncEnumerable and stream that data in the API. Is this possible

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add some information about how you are populating the `List<T> Data` now? Then we can explore how that list can be streamed asynchronously instead.

Comment: HTTP doesn't allow streaming results and `IAsyncEnumerable` doesn't change that. What it allows is writing the results you already have directly to the response stream as they arrive, not implement a server-push stream the way SignalR or gRPC do.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Paged results aren't supposed to be so many they need streaming themselves. If you really want to use streaming, you should probably return the metadata in headers, not the body, allowing you to return Data items using `IAsyncEnumerable`. If you really want to push data to clients though, it's better to use a protocol that does support pushing and streaming